# Prevent drop of certain elements on hosted Windows Forms Designer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drag-and-drop, design-time

How can I block dropping of certain objects onto container controls in hosted WinForms designer (`System.Windows.Forms.Design`) ?

So far I was only able to block it by providing my own subclass of `ParentControlDesigner` that overrides `OnDragEnter` and sets `e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None` when condition is met but this has several problems:

1. Most containers have their own designer subclasses forcing me to duplicate a lot of code
2. Certain designers (e.g. `PanelDesigner`) are internal and cannot be subclassed

Is there a way to control drag and drop in single place or at least without extending every possible designer (maybe somehow with `System.Windows.Forms.Design.Behavior`) ?

Comment: No, not exactly easy.  You'd have to replace the designer for the form, a DocumentDesigner derived class that's also hidden.  Reimplementing the IToolboxUser.GetToolSupported() gives you the way to block the selection.  Adding the FormDocumentDesigner methods back is the painful part.

Comment: Actually I already have a subclass of DocumentDesigner and block drops in OnDragEnter and OnDragDrop but this doesn't help. I would have to override CanDropComponents which is internal.